# R - unpacking nested list of t.test results

Tags: r, list, nested

I have a data frame `attended` with 12 pairs of pre/post numerical metrics (columns), and computing a t-test for each pair.

Here is the function that does a single test:

```
attended_test <- function(pre, post) {
tryCatch(t.test(log10(attended[pre]+1), log10(attended[post]+1), alternative 
= "greater", paired = FALSE,
              var.equal = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95), error=function(e) 
c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA")) 
}
```

Creating vectors that correspond to data frame's columns:

```
pre <- as.list(c(4,5,6,7,8,9,16,17,18,19,20,21))
post <- as.list(c(10,11,12,13,14,15,22,23,24,25,26,27))
```

Applying test function to each pair of columns:

```
attended_test_results_list <- mapply(attended_test, pre, post, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
```

The problem I'm having is unlisting `attended_test_results_list` into a single data frame. This structure is a list of 12 list objects for each test (aka nested list).

I identified the attributes I want from each test result's list:

```
data.frame(t(unlist(attended_test_results_list[[1]][c("estimate","p.value","statistic","conf.int")])))
```

Which has an output like so:

```
estimate.mean.of.x estimate.mean.of.y   p.value statistic.t   conf.int1 conf.int2
1          0.2476742          0.2530888 0.5950925  -0.2407039 -0.04243605       Inf
```

I want to create a single data frame with 1 row for each test (12 rows) like above. I've used `lapply` plenty of times, and I understand that I need to execute the code above for each of the 12 lists in `attended_test_results_list` and row bind to a single data frame.

But with this function I am getting this error:

```
attended_unpacked_test_results <- lapply(attended_test_results_list, 
function(x){
data.frame(t(unlist(attended_test_results_list[[x]]
[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","conf.int")])))
})

Error in attended_test_results_list[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

Do I need to be using a second `lapply` somewhere? How can create the data frame in the format I want?

Comment: I only get `NAs` with your data and function `attended_test`...Is that expected? What is `attended`?

Comment: the NAs are from the tryCatch wrapper that exists around the t.test function. If the test cannot be computed for whatever reason it returns NA for each of the 9 elements the test ordinarily outputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be enough with one `lapply`. You get the error because you are passing a list to the argument `x`. This is why you get the error `invalid subscript type 'list'`.

I am not sure, but this should work:

```
attended_unpacked_test_results <- lapply(attended_test_results_list, function(x) {
  data.frame(t(unlist(x[c("estimate","p.value","statistic","conf.int")])))
})
```

This will return a list. Possibly `sapply` will return a data frame.

Comment: This converts each list into a data frame, but I can rbind into a single data frame from there. thank you very much sir!